# I am facing this issue in django framework

Tags: python, django, numpy

-while I am making a project in django

- django -admin startproject hello

-I am facing this issue in django , while using this command server is not working

-python manage.py runserver

-server show this error:

-python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: please share your project structure.

Comment: Are you in the right folder? The one with `manage.py`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved by updating the version of python,

old version of python was 2.7, after update version of python is 11.3,

after that problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the fact that you must put a dot after the hello command so that it is placed inside the main file, Hello and manage.py are placed, in this case you can access the manager.
I hope this answer was useful

Finally:

~python manage.py runserver (8000 or 9000)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are not in the project directory.
Before running manage.py you have to cd into your project folder.
Do:

```
cd hello
```

Then run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

It should work now!